# void method recursion error

Tags: java, recursion

thanks in advance for your help, basically i'm trying to exit the recursion of a void method but some funny things are happening before and after the return statement.basically the program is to find a path through a maze, so once it prints YES , the return statement should prevent any further recursion of the rec(int x,int y) method, but it still prints after printing YES , so thats my question.so except for printing YES and NO all the other println statements basically used them for debugging , so if you observe, before printing YES the println statements print 'x' as 4 and 'y' as 1, but then after return statement their values have changed to 2 and 1, how is that possible when there is no further code to manipulate their values.

```css
static int x,y,fx,fy;
static char g[][]={ //your maze array , # represents wall and . represents path};
static Stack<Integer>stackx=new Stack<Integer>();
static Stack<Integer>stacky=new Stack<Integer>();
// both of the stacks are used for reverting changes int he maze to original
public static void main(String args[])
{
    x=y=0;
  for(int i=0;i<g.length;i++)
  {
   for(int j=0;j<g[i].length;j++)
   {
    if(g[i][j]=='S')
    {
     x=j;
     y=i;
    }
    else if(g[i][j]=='G')
    {
     fx=j;
     fy=i;
    }
   }
  }
    rec(x,y);
    System.out.println("HEllooooooo");
}
public static void rec(int x,int y)
{
   try
   {
       System.out.println(x+" "+y+" "+check);
       if(x==fx && y==fy)
       {
           System.out.println("YES");
           check=true;
           x=y=0;
           return;
       }
       System.out.println(x+" "+y+" "+check);
       if(check==false)
       {
                         revert();// reverts maze back to original
   change(); // slides walls in the maze
 
  for(int i=0;i<g.length;i++)
  {
   for(int j=0;j<g[0].length;j++)
   {
    System.out.print(g[i][j]);
   }
   System.out.println("");
  }
  if(!valid(x,y+1))
  {
   if(!((y+1)>(g.length-1)))
   {
    g[y+1][x]='#';
   }
  }
  else
  {
   rec(x,y+1);
  }
  if(!valid(x+1,y))
  {
   if(!((x+1)>(g[0].length-1)))
   {
    g[y][x+1]='#';
   }
  }
  else
  {
   rec(x+1,y);
  }
  if(!valid(x-1,y))
  {
   if(!((x-1)>=0))
   {
    g[y][x-1]='#';
   }
  }
  else
  {
   rec(x-1,y);
  }
  if(!valid(x,y-1))
  {
   if(!((y-1)>=0))
   {
    g[y-1][x]='#';
   }
  }
  else
  {
   rec(x,y-1);
  }
       }
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
     {
        System.out.println("NO");
        return;
     }
}
```

and the out put is as follows

```css
4 1 false
YES      // output is correct and should end but it continues//
2 1 true //x and y values change from 4,1 to 2,1 even with no code to manipulate them
2 1 true
3 0 true
3 0 true
4 0 true
4 0 true
NO
1 1 true
1 1 true
0 1 true
0 1 true
NO
HEllooooooo
```

Comment: I do believe the //code part is also relevant here. Currently the method is not even recursive ;)

Comment: And what about that in the main()?

Comment: tempted to try System.exit(0), but the question demands more than one use case, so had to resort to return, but i have never encountered anything like this before

Comment: A little bit of effort on the format of this question might be handy (indentation in particular).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If hitting fx,fy is the ultimate goal, then:

```
boolean rec( int x, int y )
```

After "YES" is printed:

```
return true;
```

All recursive calls rec( ..., ... ) should be replaced by

```
if( rec( ..., ... ) ) return true;
```

This should bring you out of the recursion.

And the last return:

```
return false;
```

Comment: that solved it, but do you know the reason why x and y took random values?

Comment: There were unnecessary additional calls to rec where some more (futile) searching was being done. Let's assume that the first call to rec (within rec) finds fx and fy: the call returns and then the next call to rec (valid() permitting) is entered where another neighbour of the original cell is tested. Printing the global variable `check` is misleading, it just reflects that unnecessary work is being done.